# Saving Training Input ROI using the SCP dock within QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have just downloaded QGIS and installed the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin. I am trying to evaluate whether this tool will be of use in creating polygons from high resolution satellite imagery that represent land cover.

Following through the tutorial I am encountering issues when trying to save an ROI.I have successfully created an ROI polygon, and in the classification dock added the MC info and C info when I click on the icon to save the ROI into the training input, the following error message keeps appearing.

```
2017-05-22T13:29:38 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/sruddick/.qgis2/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\classificationdock\classificationdock.py", line 2240, in saveROItoShapefile cfg.utls.calculateSignature(cfg.shpLay, cfg.rstrNm, [self.ROILastID], cfg.ROIMacroID, cfg.ROIMacroClassInfo, cfg.ROIID, cfg.ROIInfo, 50, 40, "No", "No", UID)
              File "C:/Users/sruddick/.qgis2/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\core\utils.py", line 1661, in calculateSignature bX = cfg.utls.clipRasterByShapefile(tLP, tS, None)
              File "C:/Users/sruddick/.qgis2/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\core\utils.py", line 2779, in clipRasterByShapefile check = cfg.utls.vectorToRaster(cfg.emptyFN, shapefile, cfg.emptyFN, tRxs, raster, conversionType, "GTiff", burnValues)
              File "C:/Users/sruddick/.qgis2/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\core\utils.py", line 5320, in vectorToRaster lPRS = cfg.utls.getEPSGVector(layerPath)
              File "C:/Users/sruddick/.qgis2/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\core\utils.py", line 5222, in getEPSGVector lP.AutoIdentifyEPSG()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'AutoIdentifyEPSG'
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before and can help me resolve this so I can test out the capability of this plugin?

Comment: Which version of the plugin and QGIS version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I am using QGIS 2.18.7. I have come back to this today and after deleting the scp file that I created yesterday this now seems to be working. Not sure what the cause of the issue was here but I am now able to save my training examples and have successfully run the classification process several times without this message cropping up.